# C# winforms приложение, настройка MySqlconnection для локальной сети

Tags: c#, mysql

Я создал приложение C #, которое хочу запустить в локальной сети, чтобы разные ПК в одной сети могли установить мое приложение и получить доступ к базе данных, хранящейся на серверном ПК, то есть при входе приложение спрашивает у пользователя логин пароль, они хранятся на базе данных. сервер MAMP,

**вот строка подключения**

```
class Database
{
    MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=telecom");
    
    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        if (Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        Connection.Open();
    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        if (Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            Connection.Close();

    }

    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return Connection;
    }
}
```

`

**вот строки извлечения логин и  пароля пользователей из БД**

```
` public partial class giris : Form
{
    public vhod()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       loginwwod.Text = "логин";
       loginwwod.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

       parolwwod.Text = "пароль";
     parolwwod.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                          
          string loginUser = loginwwod.Text;
          string passUser = parolwwod.Text;

          Database database = new Database();

          DataTable table = new DataTable();

          MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

          MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `password` = @uP", database.getConnection());

          command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;

          command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

          adapter.SelectCommand = command;

          adapter.Fill(table);

          if (table.Rows.Count > 0)

          {
              this.Hide();
              menu menu1 = new menu();
              menu1.Show();

          }

          else
              MessageBox.Show("неправильно!");    

    }`
```

помогите пожалуйста разобраться , не судите строго, я только начинаю, всем огромное спасибо!

Comment: А вопрос в чем? Что не получается?

Comment: я на другом компьютере ( в одной локальной сети) пытаюсь вводит логин пароль  который хранится на БД, но ошибку выдает, пишет нет соединения с БД , не знаю как настроит строку подключение чтобы другие ПК могли извлечь логин пароль из БД

Comment: `localhost` - это алиас для 127.0.0.1 - то есть _этот_ компьютер. То есть ваша программа ищет БД на том компьютере, где она запущена.

Comment: Вам нужно выставить сервер MySql на общедоступный IP. И с других компьютеров подключаться по этому адресу IP.

Comment: не подскажите как это сделать ? допустим IP адрес моего компьютера где установлен сервер 192.168.1.105 , все компьютеры где я буду тестировать программу находятся в этой подсети (192.168.1.106, 107,108) теперь я должен отредактировать php файл сервера ?

Comment: вот мой config.inc.php файл                                                                          
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306'; // MySQL port 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root'; // MySQL password

Answer (score 0):

Задайте адрес сервера при создании соединения

```cs
MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.105;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=telecom");
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: я сделал это, но в этом случае даже мой ПК ( где стоит сервер )не может подключится , выдает такую ошибку   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Authentication to host '192.168.1.105' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'admin-admin' (using password: YES)"

Comment: в просторах гулга прочитал про то, что надо создать новую учетную запись правами , CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;   может я не туда лезу ....

Comment: @Misterjunior Правильно. У вас должна быть учетная запись `'username'@'%'` (в вашем случае `'root'@'%'` или `'root'@'192.168.1.%'`) для возможности подключения пользователя `root` с любого хоста

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, после этого еще нужно изменит исходник config.inc.php ?

Comment: @Misterjunior А PHP тут каким местом?

Comment: благодарю ! сделал как выше написано, все вроде бы заработал, создал новый пользователь дал разрешение на все что можно ( но это не правильно  как мне сказали )  вместе локалхоста дал IP компьютера на котором работает сервер , но почему то подключение плохо работает или медленно , надо разобраться , самое главное что сработал !)

Comment: @Misterjunior [skip_name_resolve](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_name_resolve)